# Software Tester Tests and exercises for Interviews (junior level)

Tags: interview

Just a quick question, I'm running interviews for a Junior Tester role to work with me, and would like to give a Software Tester Test to help filter through applicants - does anyone know of any good ones out on the internet.

I've written an exercise to be run in an interview situation, but it would really be handy if there was an online based one that I could set - do any of you know of any companies or websites that provide such a service?

Many thanks in advance for any answers or help with this!

Comment: 1: Plenty of them around on Google. 2: If you use interview questions from the internet, others can find them too; does it not defeat the purpose of having an interview?

Comment: Instead of closing this, we may want to make this authoritative resource to learning material for QA (or link to other such questions), and link such answer prominently to avoid FAQ questions.

Comment: Manual or Automated Tester ?  That is key to providing an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use:

- ITSQB syllabus for some theoretical questions.
- great task are on [testingchallenges](http://testingchallenges.thetestingmap.org/index.php) especialy task 1 and 6
- also i take inspiration from codility, leetcode or hackerrank*
- [Test from google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKu_SEDAykw), add question how test it to it and you have challenge

*sorry i can put only two links

Answer (score 0):

**Relevant links are as follow:**

1. Here is the [link](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/software-testing-interview-questions/) which covers almost everything related to testing, testing processes etc. that you would like to ask the candidate
2. Some puzzles to check the problem solving approach. You can get many such websites but the one that I like is [this](https://www.indiabix.com/puzzles/number-puzzles/).

The third important factor is communication and personality . But, this is not much relevant here since you are looking for help on testing.

I hope that the details will be helpful to you.